# Defining The Size of an Array Based on the Size of a String

Tags: c++, string, size

I want the size of test_2 to be equal to the number of characters user inputs into test_1.

For example, if the user enters "Hello", test_2[n] becomes test_2[4].

The following code doesn't work:

```
std::string test_1;
cin >> text;
int n = text.size();
std::string test_2[n];
```

Gives me the error that "n" has to be a constant value. Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: can you clarify whether `test2` is meant to be an array of `n` strings, or a single string with length `n` ?  And how do you calculate `4` as the length of `Hello` ?

Comment: Thank you for your attention, Matt. test_2 is meant to be an array of n strings. Hello's length = 4 based on -> length - 1.

Comment: So you actually want the dimension of `test_2` to be one less than the number of characters the user input (not "equal to" as you said in your first line) ?

Comment: Yes. Basically I said equal as test_2 is an array starting from index 0.

Comment: maybe you misunderstand - if the array has dimension 4 then it has 4 entries whose indices are 0,1,2,3.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can get `text.size()` many empty `strings`:

```
std::vector<std::string> test_2 (n);
```

That is the preferred (only real) way to get a dynamically sized array in C++. Do not do it with `new[]`. It is bad. Really, really bad.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any other way to do this? Because after using that first code, I won't be able to use the sort function to sort the words in test_2. And after using the second code I won't be able to use test_2[i] = test_1.substr(i, test_1.size() - i);

Comment: @fovetobi Of course you can use the [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function on vectors. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @fovetobi The the pieces of code do different things. I listed them because it was not entirely clear to me what you meant. If you want to sort words, you most likely need the first one. But *"How can I sort words?"* would be another question. (There is a one question per question rule here on SO, so you would need to start a new one).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I actually want to sort words and I already have done it, and my program works. But I have done it with defining test_2 as test_2[32]. But I don't want to define a constant value for test_2 (as the user input's string might vary) so that's why I opened up this question.

Comment: @fovetobi I do not know your code or your requirements, but I would guess that something like `void mySort(std::vector<std::string>& input) {/* sort logic here*/}` should suite your needs. `n` does not need to be constant here at all. You should prefer [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) over your own sort of course if you are allowed to. It is most likely much better than yours. :) However, the answer to the question you posted is on top of my answer, how to use it with your sort function a different one.

Comment: OP has clarified he/she does not want the single string option